# How to get the gridview textbox control ID in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have ASP.NET Gridview and Textbox control in it. Now I want to get the Textbox ID in java script.
I had already referred this question in stack overflow but I couldn't get the exact answer.

My Gridview Template Code is

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amt Recieve Now" ControlStyle-Width="100">
   <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAmountReceiveNow" runat="server" CssClass="textboxRight"
        AutoPostBack="true" OnFocus= "GVtxtAmount()"
        OnTextChanged="txtAmountReceiveNow_TextChange" 
                Text='<%#Eval("AMOUNT_RECEIVE_NOW")%>'>
     </asp:TextBox>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and Javascript code is as follows :

```
 function GVtxtAmount() {
    var txtAmountReceive = document.getElementById(
                  '<%= ((GVMaintainReceiptMaster)Container)
                         .FindControl("txtAmountReceiveNow").ClientID %>');
    var selection = txtAmountReceive.value.indexOf(".");
    alert(selection);
 };
```

**GVMaintainReceiptMaster** is ID of GridView

Help me to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function GVtxtAmount() {
        var txtAmountReceive = $("input[id*=txtAmountReceiveNow]")
        var selection = txtAmountReceive.value.indexOf(".");
        alert(selection);
};
```

Comment: I got the following run time error : **Microsoft JScript runtime error: '$' is undefined**

Comment: you have to include jquery file refrenc.Add this line in header <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" ></script> . I didn't understand what you want to store in selection.

Comment: In my textbox I have the value 25000.00 now I want to store the index value of . in selection variable

Comment: any success in your objective or any error message you are getting?

Comment: Getting Error Message that **jquery file was not found**

Answer (score 1):

You can't get text box in this way. Here is the work-around I hope it will help.

```
function GVtxtAmount() {
        var GVMaintainReceiptMaster = document.getElementById('<%= GVMaintainReceiptMaster.ClientID %>');

        for (var rowId = 1; rowId < GVMaintainReceiptMaster.rows.length; rowId++) {
            var txtbx = GVMaintainReceiptMaster.rows[rowId].cells[0].children[0];
            alert(txtbx.value);
        }
        return false;
    }
```